# Saving Placement of a Draggable Button within the UIView into Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiview, draggable

I would like to be able to save the placement of the draggable button within the UIView created by a user on the click of the add button (in the navigation bar )into core data so that when the user saves the data and calls upon it from the tableview cell created by the core data that it is in the same place where the user saved it. I already have my core data set up i just want to know what si the best way to go about this whether I should use NSKeyedArchiver or something else. Here is my code and here are some pictures for better understanding.

Chart .m

```
@interface ChartViewController ()

@end

@implementation ChartViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Chart";


}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];

    CGRect buttonRect = self.buttonField.frame;


    CGPoint point = [aTouch locationInView:self.buttonField.superview];



    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(buttonRect, point)) {
            _buttonField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
            _draggedView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        for (_buttonField in self.view.subviews) {
            _buttonField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

        }

    }


}

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ) {
        gesture.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;


        UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Would you like to delete the selected rep(s)?"
                                      message:nil
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* deleteButton = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:@"Delete"
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)

                                       {
                                           for (_buttonField in self.view.subviews) {
                                               if ([[UIColor colorWithCGColor:_buttonField.layer.borderColor] isEqual:[UIColor whiteColor]]) {

                                                   [_buttonField removeFromSuperview];

                                               }
                                           }

                                        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                    }];
        UIAlertAction* cancelButton = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                       {






                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                   }];

        [alert addAction:deleteButton];
        [alert addAction:cancelButton];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}




- (void)panWasRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner {
    {

        panner.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;


       _draggedView = panner.view;

        CGPoint offset = [panner translationInView:_draggedView.superview];
        CGPoint center = _draggedView.center;
        _draggedView.center = CGPointMake(center.x + offset.x, center.y + offset.y);


        _draggedView.layer.masksToBounds =YES;
        _buttonField.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;


        // Reset translation to zero so on the next `panWasRecognized:` message, the
        // translation will just be the additional movement of the touch since now.
        [panner setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:_draggedView.superview];

    }

}

-(void)buttonTouched:(UIButton*)sender forEvent:(id)tap {
    NSSet *touches = [tap allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    touch.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor
                                    ].CGColor;
}


-(void)doubleTapped:(UIButton*)sender forEvent:(id)twoTaps {
    NSSet *touches = [twoTaps allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    touch.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

}
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem*)saveRep {


    saveCount ++;
    if (saveCount == 1) {

        self.title = @"Chart";


        for (_buttonField in self.view.subviews) {


            _buttonField.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

            _buttonField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;


            saveCount = 0;

        }
    }
}
- (IBAction)editButton:(UIBarButtonItem*)editRep {


    editCount ++;
    if (editCount == 1) {

        self.title = @"Edit Mode";


        for (_buttonField in self.view.subviews) {

            _buttonField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


            editCount = 0;
        }

    }
}


- (IBAction)addRepButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)newRep {

    self.labelCounter++;

    buttonCount ++;
    if (buttonCount > 0 )
    {

        _buttonField = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 300, 28, 28)];
        [_buttonField setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.labelCounter]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _buttonField.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
        _buttonField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _buttonField.layer.cornerRadius = 14;
        _buttonField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        _buttonField.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
        _buttonField.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
        [_buttonField setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _buttonField.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        _buttonField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


        //Pan gesture declared in button
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panWasRecognized:)];
        [_buttonField addGestureRecognizer:panner];

        //Long Press gesture declared in button
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
        [self.buttonField addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

        //Touch down inside declared in button
        [self.buttonField addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        //Double Tap inside declared in button
        [self.buttonField addTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapped:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];


        [self.view addSubview:(_buttonField)];




    }


}

- (void) saveData {
    NSMutableDictionary *dataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
    if (_buttonField != nil) {
        [dataDict setObject:_buttonField forKey:@"placement"];  // save the placement array
    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Rep"];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:dataDict toFile:filePath];
}
```

[Picture of ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUpAr.png)

When the user presses done I want to save it from there into the core data. Thank you!!

Comment: This is such a small amount of data that I wouldn't bother with the overhead of CoreData. I would just save an `NSValue` to `NSUserDefaults` instead. WAY simpler.

Comment: The reason why I want to use core data is because I want that specific object to be linked with the specific data that is stored within the core data string. I know this is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `CGRect` there is also an easy way out by using a string which is already a standard data type in Core Data.

```
// Swift and Objective-C
object.rect = NSStringFromCGRect(frame)
view.frame = CGRectFromString(object.rect)
```

While `NSValue` is also a good option, this is also eminently *readable*.

Answer (score 0):

In your data model add a transformable called something like boundingRect. Then when your user finishes dragging the button say something like:

```
managedObject.boundingRect = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:button.frame];
```

Then when you want to read it out of the database say:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame: [managedObject.boundingRect CGRectValue]];
```